# How to save date into database with current time?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table in database, one of the row adds add while something was done/acomplished. And it works fine. But.. it doesn't add current time. When I prints out date from db, it shows `2016-12-13 00:00`. Instead of for example `2016-12-13 15:32`. How do I add current time?
This is how my sql looks

```
    [example_date]  DATE         NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @RachitGupta Is it better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `date` data type does not have a time component.  You want either `datetime` or `datetime2` (or perhaps `smalldatetime`):

```
example_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
```

You can review the documentation for the various date/time data types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. That is what i thought.. simple "date" alone seemed to be too empty